# When I deploy azure funtions app using VS Code, it's not working. And showing "Central Directory corrupt" comment

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I create Azure Functions App using VS Code.

Without any modification, deployment of this project is working.

But, After add any dependency in pom.xml, deployment of this project is not working.

And showing "Central Directory corrupt" comment.

How can I deploy this project with adding any dependency in pom.xml

Comment: This happens due to a restriction on your network. Maybe try it from a phone hotspot for time being and get back to me

Comment: @HariHaran It's not possible to use a phone hotspot because of security policy. But, I can register a exception of the security policy. What is the destination ip of exception?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on two workstations, but managed to resolve it by following these steps:

- Uninstall VSCODE
- Remove the .vscode folder in your user folder
- Rename your workspace folder
- Reinstall VSCODE and first install the Azure Tools extension.

[image: at]